# Read event error logs for specific application

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

Hi i'm trying to make a c# console application that will monitor copychimp.exe if it sets an error on event logs on current date
Here's what i have try

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string eventlofName = "Application";
            EventLog logs = new EventLog();
            logs.Log = eventlofName;

            foreach(EventLogEntry log in logs.Entries){
                Console.WriteLine("{0}\n" + log.Message);
            }
        }
```

this is my step and don't know whats next.
I have no control on Copychimp.exe.

Here's the error on event logs i want to capture

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name=".NET Runtime" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">1026</EventID> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-10-18T05:26:38.001427000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>17564</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>PHCAB01DT0160.NWS.NEXPERIA.COM</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>Application: CopyChimpServer.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.IndexOutOfRangeException at CopyChimpServer.Program.Main(System.String[])</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Out put if copychimp.exe has an error on event logs in event viewer check if it is equals to date now it should print "An error Occured an CopyChimp.exe "

the reason for this app is to monitor if copychimp.exe has crashed in order to re run it, it is running on server so there should be a other app that will monitor copychimp

Hope you understand what i mean 
Sorry for my bad english

Comment: What is input? what is expected output? Can you elaborate your question in detail? currently it is unclear to me

Comment: sorry i'm not good at english by the way i updated my question hope you understand